# ModuleNotFoundError at the end of py file weirdness

Tags: python, traceback, modulenotfounderror

Long story short - I'm on a different laptop, and it is a work laptop where I am probably not administrator level.  With that, I installed python, then pandas, numPY, pyodbc, docx-mailmerge and instead of doing "pip install" I did "py -m pip install ..." to get those in because just "pip install" didn't work.

I've been tweaking the routine that worked on my dead laptop, and finally got it to run to the end. My routine imports an access database, reads in the information and parses the rich text field to remove the html tags, and writes the data out to a word template and creates a new word document.

When it reaches the end of the commands, I get the lines

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py11.py'; 'py11' is not a package**

If I try to do "import py11.py" again, I just get those lines.  I thought it might be having problems with writing a file to somewhere other than a c: drive where the word template was, so I changed them both to be in the document directory, and I looked at the current directory, and it is where it should be.  I currently am exiting out of python, and getting back in and then I can run this one time, and start getting the traceback messages again.  TIA for any help.

Comment: where is the sample code?

Comment: I would like to see your code, if you don't mind.

Comment: It's better if you can provide a sample directory layout for your code too. Sometimes, import is fail due to the file is not in the right directory.

Comment: I tried to add the code, but I couldn't put the entire file in the question.  This routine worked without problem on the dead laptop, Right now, the word template and the newly created document land in my documents directory on the c: drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ever had those kind of errors, but I had some problems  with basic python things not working all of suddent for no reason, what the best way to fix those for me was restarting the installation file and then click on repair.

[image: file to run]

[image: the gui]

it may seem kinda obvious, so you may have tried it already but it has been actually useful for me quite a few time

I don't have enough reputation to post this as a comment so I made an answer even though I don't know if it will actually solve your problem

and also when importing a module I don't think that you should put a .py at the end

Comment: Ok, I did it without a .py and just "import py11" and it seemed to work and the same error didn't appear. I'm still a newbie even though I've worked with other languages, so that seems very strange.  However, I can't just do "import py11" again.  Weird. Thanks.

Comment: ok now I can add a comment. Ok so basically for any module or file that you wrote or install on the same directory, you should be able to import the code, by using 'import [name of file/module]' and you can add a 'as [a name]' so that when you call a function of that file/module, you don't have to write the whole name of this file/module but just the '[name]' that you chose for it. and there are never .py as far I as know at the end

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'm sort of brute forcing doing routines to learn python.  Everything is interesting and it is so fun.  It was sort of weird because I looked at the bitcoin hashing routine recently, and one of the things I have to do in the new routine I'm working on, is to compare files in a directory, and a hash may be a quicker way to compare files that will show if they are duplicates.